# picking select box based on index

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a scenario that dynamically show multiple select box. So I want pick value of select box based on index.

```
<select class="monday">
    <option value="NONE"> --SELECT--<option>
    <c:forEach items="${employees.roster}" var="roster">
    <option value="${roster.shiftValue}">${roster.shiftId} /${roster.shiftValue}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

[image]

Iterating it getting one by one is not working for my scenario. If I pass 1 as index first select box selected value should return and so on.

Comment: You need `:eq` selector.

Comment: $('.monday').val(), this will get the first select box value.

Comment: What jQuery function are you passing this index into?

Comment: moopet, Got the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:eq` selector to target element by index:

```
$('.monday:eq(1)').val(),// This will give second select box value. as index for eq selector starts from 0
```

Comment: That's great. Works Fine.